# How to prevent CSS Flex / Grid layouts to be reversed on dir="RTL"

Tags: css, flexbox, grid, internationalization

I have a simple `div` (`grid layout` but the same would apply to `flexbox`), which shows three different `text` elements.

The problem is that whenever my `html`'s `dir` attribute is set to `rtl`, the order of the grid items changes, and I'd like to be able to prevent that change in that specific case (where content order is not based on writing direction, but for semantic value.

For example's sake, here's what my items look like:

```js
let direction = 'rtl';
document.getElementById('toggle-direction').addEventListener('click', () => {
  direction = direction === 'rtl' ? 'ltr' : 'rtl';

  document.documentElement.setAttribute('dir', direction);
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.left-arrow {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;

  margin-inline-end: auto;
}

.center-content {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  text-align: center;
}

.right-arrow {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 3 / 4;

  margin-inline-start: auto;
  
}

#toggle-direction {
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="left-arrow"><</span>
  <span class="center-content">Center content</span>
  <span class="right-arrow">></span>
  <button id="toggle-direction">Toggle direction</button>
</div>
```

PS: I could add `direction: ltr;` to the `.container` selector, but that would create an undesired styling, since I want to use inline-oriented styling.

Comment: specify the direction on the grid container to be ltr

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I improved the code to exemplify why simply adding `direction: ltr` is not a solution

Answer (score 0):

Is my understanding you only want the arrows to keep their orientation.
So you should isolate and wrap the elements you want the direction to consistent in containers with consistent flow direction (and put everything you want to update outside that containers) like so :

```js
let direction = 'rtl';
document.getElementById('toggle-direction').addEventListener('click', () => {
  direction = direction === 'rtl' ? 'ltr' : 'rtl';

  document.documentElement.setAttribute('dir', direction);
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.ltr {
  direction: ltr;
 }

.left-arrow {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  text-align: center;
}

.center-content {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  text-align: center;
}

.right-arrow {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  text-align: center;
}

#toggle-direction {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}
```

```html
<!-- inherit direction flow --> 
<div class="container ltr">
  <!-- ltr direction flow --> 
  <p class="left-arrow">Left arrow</p>
  <p class="center-content">Center content</p>
  <p class="right-arrow">Right arrow</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <!-- inherit direction flow -->
  <button id="toggle-direction">Toggle direction</button>
</div>
```

Edits done: wrapped the first row you had inside the container in another container (`class="colum rtl"`) that always has a direction.
Small css updates to keep the view.

Alternatively you could place the arrows container inside the container with the button. But in order to have consistent `rtl` direction you will need to wrap them there in a container (with `class="rtl"`) and you need a little more updates to your css to keep the aspect.

Alternatively if there is really no way for you to isolate all the components you need to have consistent direction you could for some specific cases create a class `class="inherit-direction"` (for example) and in your js, when you change the direction of the document, change the containers direction with that class as well (`document.getElementsByClassName("inherit-direction")` and iterate trough them).

But I would strongly advise to use this last option only as last measure and limit the number of uses as much as possible.

Comment: This is the problem with such a simplistic example. The problem is that now, every child component of `.container` will be a _ltr-direction-based_ element, and will lose all the matching styles provided from `dir="rtl"`. I'll improve my example.

Comment: The best way would be to wrap the components where you want to have consistent flow in separate containers and add a generic class to them . So everything outside inherits the body and only what is inside those containers  stays ltr (I will update the example for a better understanding)